# How to highlight occurrences of a search term in text in Visual Studio editor for C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, highlighting

hello I have Visual Studio 2008 Express edition, I found some add-ins like `metalscroll` and `rockscroll` and even installed, but I can't find how to use those add-ins, I thought it might be automatically, I mean highlighting, but it doesn't work for my version, any ideas why? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [metalscroll's home page](http://code.google.com/p/metalscroll/):

> The add-in works with Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 (Express versions
>   not supported, since they don't allow add-ins). VS 2010 will not be
>   supported, but Microsoft has released an add-in pack called
>   Productivity Power Tools which provides the same functionality.

You can forget about installing add-ins in Express editions of Visual Studio. They simply are not supported. Money spending time :-)